# NordVPN Status shortcut

Tags: command-line, scripts, shortcuts

How can I create an icon on desktop in Ubuntu 20.04, which open Terminal and write out NordVPN status in Terminal. Command is "nordvpn status". I have .sh file, but when open Terminal, immediately close and I cann't read the result.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e nordvpn status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest method would be to wait for a keypress at the end of your script.
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# gnome-terminal -e nordvpn status
nordvpn status
read -n1 -p "Press any key..."
```

Comment: This won't work. the `gnome-terminal -e nordvpn status` opens a new terminal which closes immidiately after the command `nordvpn status`, while the parent terminal stays open and waits to read `x`. One solution is to get rid of the `gnome-terminal -e` part. So that all the commands are executed in the same terminal.

Comment: user68186 is right: I am editing the answer.